# Display all the leafs on the same level with D3.JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

I recently started to use D3.js in order to visualize a tree in the form of a radial tree, as presented in [Colapsible Radial Tree](http://codepen.io/fernoftheandes/pen/pcoFz?editors=0010) , but I encountered some problems while modifying the code.

I used the code in [1](http://codepen.io/fernoftheandes/pen/pcoFz?editors=0010) to display all the leafs on the same 'level'. My methodology is the following:

First, compute the maximum depth of the tree to know where to put all the leafs of the tree, by using the following code:

```
var maxDepth = getDepth(source);
function getDepth(obj) {
var depth = 0;
if (obj.children) {
    obj.children.forEach(function (d) {
        var tmpDepth = getDepth(d)
        if (tmpDepth > depth) {
            depth = tmpDepth
        }
    })
}
return 1 + depth}
```

Then, loop over all the nodes of the tree and whenever a node without children is encountered (= leaf), the position is set to:

```
nodes.forEach(function(d) {
if (d.children)
  {
    d.y = d.depth * 60;
  }else
    d.y = maxDepth * 60;})
```

It seems to work correctly, except that the positions of some nodes are not correct and are overlapping some times. [image: Radial Tree]

How can I adjust the code to spread the nodes on a more efficient way ? The full code is available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/u1xm61yg/).

Comment: maybe just use the default depth

Comment: you wont get the correct positions this way as the data set is a tree (has children). I would recommend flattening the data and passing it to the d3.radial agani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use d3's *cluster* layout, it's designed to place leaves at the same level

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Cluster-Layout

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570

```
var tree = d3.layout.cluster()
    .size([360, diameter / 2 - 80])
    .separation(function(a, b) { return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 5) / a.depth; });

...

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  //nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 80; }); // get rid of this line (or amend it) as it resets the leaves to one level below the parent
```